# Realtime Monitoring-%iowait

Tags: shell

I am new to scripting and i know the question below is very simple but not getting anything in google :(.. please help

sar command gives the below output,

```
root@virt01:~# sar 1 1

Linux 3.19.0-42-generic (virt01.ubuntu.com)     13/02/16        _x86_64_        
(1 CPU)

12:19:55        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     
%idle

12:19:56        all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    
100.00
Average:        all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    
100.00
root@virt01:~#
```

Just want to how to check for particular value for example:%iowait and send mail alert if its exceeds 50.

If you can help it would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact end goal, I might solve the problem you have asked with a simple pipeline setup.  This particular example is brittle, so massage as appropriate, but will work given the example invocation of sar:

```
$ PERC=$(printf "%.0f" $(sar 1 1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $6'}))
$ [[ "$PERC" -ge 50 ]] && echo "IOwait% $PERC" | mail -s "iowait over 50%" -t "you@example.com"
```

Parts:

- `sar 1 1` -> you know
- `tail -1` -> take just the last "average" line
- `awk '{print $6'}` -> prints the 6th column, the %IOwait

The above pipline results in some percentage like "3.72".  For the next line, however, the shell will want an integer, so, `printf` to the rescue:

- `printf "%.0f" "$PERC"` -> print the float with 0 decimals, rounding as appropriate

The following line says "if greater than 50 percent execute the mail command:

- `[[ "$PERC" -ge 50 ]]` -> if greater than 50
- `&&` -> execute the next command if previous is true
- `echo "IOwait% $PERC" | mail -s "iowait over 50%" -t "you@example.com"` -> Mostly self explanatory, sending an email.